# Cannot use "this" to reference an object to create a linked list

Tags: java

I have a class (called AClass) containing an attribute of type AClass. I am trying to use this to create a linked list of integers. However, whenever I give a value to the data in AClass, it replaces the data in all the linked classes with this value.

```
public class AClass {
    public AClass rest;
    public int data;

    public AClass (int tData) {
         data=tData;
         rest=null;
    }

    public void add(int item) {
        rest=this;          //This is what is causing the problem
        data=item;
    }
```

}

This is what I am using to test. My output should be 5,6,5 but I am getting 5,6,6.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass aTest=new AClass(5);      //Creates a list with on element.
        System.out.println(aTest.data);  //Print that element for verification
        aTest.add(6); 
        System.out.println(aTest.data);      //Print the end element
        System.out.println(aTest.rest.data); //Print the next element, which should be 5
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about what a linked list is, and what your code does.

A linked list is a set of nodes chained together by a series of pointers. Based on what the expected behavior you have described, you would like a linked list built like this.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass aTest=new AClass(5);          // Data: aTest ==> (5) ==> null
        System.out.println(aTest.data);      // Prints 5.
        aTest.add(6);                        // Data: aTest ==> (6) ==> (5) ==> null
        System.out.println(aTest.data);      // Prints 6
        System.out.println(aTest.rest.data); // Prints 5
    }
}
```

However, given your implementation, you never actually create a second node--you only ever have the original node, and you corrupt your linked list.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClass aTest=new AClass(5);          // Data: aTest ==> (5) ==> null
        System.out.println(aTest.data);      // Prints 5.
        aTest.add(6);                        // Data: aTest ==> (6) ==> (6) ==> (6) ==> forever
        System.out.println(aTest.data);      // Prints 6
        System.out.println(aTest.rest.data); // Prints 6
    }
}
```

So you need `add` to create a new node:

`rest=this;` sets the next pointer to the current object, creating a circular linked list of exactly one element. You need to create a new element. You also have an interesting problem of what direction you assume you are adding items in. You can either add to the front of the list or the back of the list, but note that adding to the front means changing the pointer you have to the front. You can implement both `addFront` and `addBack` pretty easily:

```
public AClass addFront(int item) {
    AClass node = new AClass(item);
    node.rest = this;
    return node;
}

public void addBack(int item) {
    // Find the end of the list
    AClass temp = this;
    while (temp.rest != null) {
        temp = temp.rest;
    }
    temp.rest = new AClass(item);
}
```

All that being said, consider using the built-in linked list: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class AClass {
    public AClass rest;
    public int data;

    public AClass (int tData) {
         data=tData;
    }

    /**
     * Insert in front.
     * @param item data to be inserted.
     */
    public void add(int item) {
        // Make a copy of this:
        AClass copy = new AClass(data);
        copy.rest = rest;
        // Overwrite this object:
        rest = copy;
        data = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> aTest.rest.data

You are using the reference variable *aTest* to access the instance variable *rest* of type *AClass*. *Rest* holds the same reference as *aTest*. When you say *aTest.rest.data* it is another way of saying *aTest.data*, *data's* current value is **6**. That is why you are getting 5, 6, 6 as output.